# Define $m^{**}(A) = \inf\{m^*(U) \mid A \subset U \subset \Bbb R^d, U \text{ open } \}.$ Prove that $m^* (A)=m^{**}(A)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R^d$ and denote by $m^*$ the Lebesgue outer measure. Define $m^{**}(A) = \inf\{m^*(U) \mid A \subset U \subset  \Bbb R^d, U \text{ open } \}.$ Prove that $$m^* (A)=m^{**}(A)$$

Let $A \subset \Bbb R^n$ and suppose that $\{I_k\}$ is a cover for $A$. We have that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$. Let $U= \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k$.

We will first show that $m^*(A) \ge m^{**}(A)$. By definition $$m^*(A) + \varepsilon \ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k) \iff m^*(A) \ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k) - \varepsilon$$

but we also have that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k) \ge m^*(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_k) = m^*(U).$ Thus $$m^*(A) \ge m^*(U)-\varepsilon \ge m^{**}(A) - \varepsilon$$ and since this holds for any $\varepsilon >0$ we conclude that $$m^*(A) \ge m^{**}(A).$$

Now we show that $m^*(A) \le m^{**}(A)$. Note that $A \subseteq U$ so $$m^*(U) -\varepsilon \ge m^*(A) -\varepsilon$$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$. Now as $$m^{**}(A) \ge m^*(U) - \varepsilon$$ we have that $m^{**}(A) \ge m^*(A) -\varepsilon$ from where we conclude that $m^{**}(A) \ge m^*(A)$ implying that in fact $m^{**}(A) = m^*(A)$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: $m^*$ and $m^{**}$ are _exactly the same._ How do _you_ define $m^*$?